# Group by on date with SQL query?

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a view

```
ID   S.No  DateFr        DateTo
---  ----- ------       ---------
1    63    01/01/2010    01/01/2010
1    63    01/01/2010    01/11/2010
2    64    01/01/2010    01/01/2010 
2    64    01/01/2010    01/11/2010
3    65    01/01/2010    01/01/2010
3    65    01/01/2010    01/11/2010
```

Now I want results like

```
ID   S.No  DateFr       DateTo
1     63   01/01/2010   01/11/2010
2     64   01/01/2010   01/11/2010
3     65   01/01/2010   01/11/2010
```

Note Only DateFr is changed in records so I want it to shift from being a row to column.
The ID is not fixed, it can range to an unlimited no like 1,1,1 ------ 30,30,30. I am using DB2 with ISeries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,S.No,dateFr,DateTo  FROM your_table GROUP BY ID,S.No,dateFr,DateTo
```

Comment: simple GROUP BY is enough why go for pivot ?

Comment: That does not work. It returns 2 rows where I want only 1 row in place of 1,1

Comment: I think this would do SELECT ID,S.No,dateFr,DateTo  FROM your_table GROUP BY ID,S.No

Comment: It is not returning the desired output? Any idea to do this with a pivot ?

Comment: I don't have much idea of a pivot in DB2 but here is something which may help you 

http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1076604-how-pivot-dates-into-columns.html
http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/184841-pivot-invert-row-data
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1105164&page=37

+1 to GOOGLE !

Comment: A pivot table also does NOT solve the problem posted in this question.  See Brandon's answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as something like this:

```
select id, s.no, min(datefr), max(dateto) from your_table group by id, s.no
```

Comment: Thanks brandon, only problem being is that the rows for id 1 are not limited to two. The can range from 4,5,6--- n rows. So the min, max won't work in that case. I need to get all rows dateTo dates in a single row in different columns or as comma separated.

Comment: Can you explain your data more?  From what you are saying I don't understand why the SQL given won't work.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work eventually Brandon. Sorry for misinterpreting your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Max()`, `Case When` and `Group By`.

In my opinion, this technique was called "Pivot" or "Crosstab".

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use SQL Server PIVOT command.

[Check this out](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/)

Comment: Sorry. Well, it's time to switch to SQLServer! :)

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to get a book on SQL.